# How can I use Jsoup selector "not"

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

```html
<div id='contents'>
<div class="article_view">
  <div class="article_txt">
      <strong>I don't want to get this point
        <br>I don't want to get this point
        <br>I don't want to get this point
      </strong>

      <div class='articlePhotoC'>
        <img src="" width='500'>
        <span class='t' style='width:480px;'>
          <b>I don't want to get this point </b>
          I don't want to get this point<br>
        </span>
        <div id='adBox' class='txt_ad' style='width:500px;'></div>
      </div>
      From here I want to get--------------
      <br><br>
      <div class='sub_cont_AD08'></div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

I have no idea how to use `notSelector` in Java.
I tried to do it like this:

```
  Elements cont = doc.select("div.article_view :not(div.article_view)");
```

but it is not working. The result includes all of "I don't want to get this point". I hope to get only "From here I want to get~~~~".

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the Text node "From here I want to get--------------" as well, or is this just a comment?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the text "From here I want to get--------------" as well, i.e. you only want to select Elements within the `<div class="article_view">` but not `<div class="article_txt">` and its children, you can do this:

```
Elements els = doc.select("div.article_view>*:not(.article_txt)");
```

This will select all Elements (`*`) that are direct children (`>`) of the div with class "article_view" except the ones with class "article_txt".

**EDIT**

Now, that it has been defined, that the elements you want are indeed children of the `div.article_txt` element, I need to modify my answer:

```
Elements els = doc.select("div.article_view>div.article_txt>*:not(strong,div.articlePhotoC)");
```

This becomes cumbersome, since you now need to define a list of stuff that should not be included. Note the comma between `strong` and `div.articlePhotoC` serving as AND operator in CSS

Comment: Can i have one more question?... How about to exclude <strong> tag?

Comment: If that answer helped, don't forget to up-vote. If it solves the problem, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: excluding the strong tag? I don't understand. Maybe you should put up a new question about this. The `<strong>` tags from your original example will not be selected by my selector, since they are children of the div that is excluded.

Comment: I got it! I tried to do as what you write down, It was working but I didn't get what I want. Because above source is strange.  <div class="article_txt"> should close over  <div class='articlePhotoC'>. But It is closed under the statement. I learned how to use what you say. Thank you so much!

Comment: The structure of your HTML is indeed very messy. Please check if my formatting of your original input is correct. Then we look what we can do